# How to use nunjuck `include` in post?

Tags: nunjucks, hexo

I'm playing around with hexo, I'm testing the nunjuck syntax which work for a small loop. However I can't find how to [include a file](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/templating.html#include), I might be wrong in the location of my file (currently next to the `.md`, in `/source/_posts`).

#### Environment Info

Node version(`node -v`):

```
node --version; npm --version
v8.9.1
5.5.1
```

#### Your site `_config.yml` (Optional):

```
# Hexo Configuration
## Docs: https://hexo.io/docs/configuration.html
## Source: https://github.com/hexojs/hexo/

# Site
title: Hexo
subtitle:
description:
author: John Doe
language:
timezone:

# URL
## If your site is put in a subdirectory, set url as 'http://yoursite.com/child' and root as '/child/'
url: http://yoursite.com
root: /
permalink: :year/:month/:day/:title/
permalink_defaults:

# Directory
source_dir: source
public_dir: public
tag_dir: tags
archive_dir: archives
category_dir: categories
code_dir: downloads/code
i18n_dir: :lang
skip_render:

# Writing
new_post_name: :title.md # File name of new posts
default_layout: post
titlecase: false # Transform title into titlecase
external_link: true # Open external links in new tab
filename_case: 0
render_drafts: false
post_asset_folder: false
relative_link: false
future: true
highlight:
  enable: true
  line_number: true
  auto_detect: false
  tab_replace:

# Home page setting
# path: Root path for your blogs index page. (default = '')
# per_page: Posts displayed per page. (0 = disable pagination)
# order_by: Posts order. (Order by date descending by default)
index_generator:
  path: ''
  per_page: 10
  order_by: -date

# Category & Tag
default_category: uncategorized
category_map:
tag_map:

# Date / Time format
## Hexo uses Moment.js to parse and display date
## You can customize the date format as defined in
## http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/
date_format: YYYY-MM-DD
time_format: HH:mm:ss

# Pagination
## Set per_page to 0 to disable pagination
per_page: 10
pagination_dir: page

# Extensions
## Plugins: https://hexo.io/plugins/
## Themes: https://hexo.io/themes/
theme: landscape

# Deployment
## Docs: https://hexo.io/docs/deployment.html
deploy:
  type:
</details>
```

#### Hexo and Plugin version(`npm ls --depth 0`):

```
"hexo": "^3.2.0",
"hexo-generator-archive": "^0.1.4",
"hexo-generator-category": "^0.1.3",
"hexo-generator-index": "^0.2.0",
"hexo-generator-tag": "^0.2.0",
"hexo-renderer-ejs": "^0.3.0",
"hexo-renderer-stylus": "^0.3.1",
"hexo-renderer-marked": "^0.3.0",
"hexo-server": "^0.2.0"
```

#### Directory Structure

```
tree ./
./
├── include
│   └── colors.html
└── _posts
    └── button6.md
```

#### Usage

```
npm install --save --only=prod hexo-include
```

In *button6.md* I added

```
{% include "include/colors.html" %}
```

#### Error

```
Unhandled rejection Template render error: (unknown path)
  Error: template not found: include/colors.html
```

#### For question

I've this post in _hexo-demo/source/*posts/button6.md*

```
---
title: button6
myitems:
  - one
  - two
---

{% for item in myitems %}
<li> {{ item }}</li>
{% endfor %}

<hr>
{% include "colors.html" %}
```

#### Question

Where am I supposed to put my `colors.html` file in order to be resolve

**related:** https://github.com/hexojs/hexo/issues/2866

Answer (score 2):

I got a same issue.
It seems hexo-include conflicting with numjack.
I changed lib/index.js following

```
hexo.extend.tag.register('include_alt', include, {asyn: true});
```

but it still won't work.
It may be because of rendering timing.
So I changed lib/index.js following

```
var fs = require('hexo-fs');
var nunjucks = require('nunjucks');
var pathFn = require('path');
// hexo.extend.tag.register('include_alt', include, { asyn: true });
hexo.extend.tag.register('include_alt', function (args) {
  var path = pathFn.join(hexo.source_dir, args[0]);  
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    nunjucks.render(path, function(err, res) {
      if (err) {
        return reject(err);
      }
      resolve(res);
    });
  });
}, {async: true});
```

then I use it as

```
{% include_alt 'some.html' %}
```

and it works.

Answer (score 0):

There is no native support for that in hexo. Tags are inspired by Octopress and the [render_partial](http://octopress.org/docs/plugins/render-partial/) tag from octopress is not present in hexo as far as I know.

Good news is there is an hexo plugin for this:

https://github.com/PirtleShell/hexo-include

Once installed, you can simply do

```
{% include colors.html %}
```

where `colors.html` would be at the root of your `source` folder

Comment: I still got the same error: `Error: template not found: include/colors.html`

Comment: Have you installed the plugin correctly ? Can you give details on where you file is stored exactly and what is the tag you have used ?

Comment: @ÉdouardLopez any luck with that? I have same problem